# Why does easy install want access to my rootfs for a "develop" install?

Tags: python, easy-install

I'm looking at a python application server and I wanted to play around with the code. I'm lead to believe passing "develop" to setup.py should leave everything in place without installing anything. However when running so it is attempting to creating directories in my rootfs.

```
./setup.py develop
```

Gives:

```
running develop
Checking .pth file support in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
error: can't create or remove files in install directory
```

I thought this might be something to do with package checking but surely attempting to write stuff into the rootfs is wrong?

Comment: Do you have right permission to write /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ directory?

Comment: @ganachoco: I could do, but I'd rather not pollute the system install. I thought the whole point of develop mode was it didn't "install" stuff on your system.

Comment: @stsquad but you cannot import something without touching anything at all.

Comment: @wRAR: I can use the system provided packages although --requires brings up a blank list so I'm not sure what it wants.

Comment: @stsquad of course you can import alrwady installed packages. I meant you cannot import new packages without "installing" them in one of the ways.

Answer (score 2):

The `develop` command wants to add a `.pth` entry for your project so that it can be imported as an egg. See the [Development mode documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#development-mode), as well as the [`develop` command docs](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#develop).

The default is to put that entry in site-packages. Set a different library path with the `--install-dir` switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--user` option ([Alternate installation: the user scheme](http://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#alternate-installation-the-user-scheme)).