# python setup package in develop mode fails

Tags: python, django, package

I am attempting to setup a simple package in develop mode:

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='rocflavors',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['ez_setup','examples','tests']),
    license='Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike license',
    long_description=open('README').read(),
    install_requires=[],
)
```

Attempt to setup: (works if I do python setup.py install)

```
(relux)roc-web5537:roc-flavors cmuench$ python setup.py install develop
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing rocflavors.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to rocflavors.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to rocflavors.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'rocflavors.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'rocflavors.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/rocflavors
copying build/lib/rocflavors/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/rocflavors
copying build/lib/rocflavors/models.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/rocflavors
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/rocflavors/templatetags
copying build/lib/rocflavors/templatetags/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/rocflavors/templatetags
copying build/lib/rocflavors/templatetags/rocflavors_extras.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/rocflavors/templatetags
copying build/lib/rocflavors/urls.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/rocflavors
copying build/lib/rocflavors/views.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/rocflavors
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/rocflavors/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/rocflavors/models.py to models.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/rocflavors/templatetags/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/rocflavors/templatetags/rocflavors_extras.py to rocflavors_extras.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/rocflavors/urls.py to urls.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/rocflavors/views.py to views.pyc
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying rocflavors.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying rocflavors.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying rocflavors.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying rocflavors.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist/rocflavors-0.0.1-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing rocflavors-0.0.1-py2.7.egg
Removing /Users/cmuench/.virtualenvs/relux/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rocflavors-0.0.1-py2.7.egg
Copying rocflavors-0.0.1-py2.7.egg to /Users/cmuench/.virtualenvs/relux/lib/python2.7/site-packages
rocflavors 0.0.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /Users/cmuench/.virtualenvs/relux/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rocflavors-0.0.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for rocflavors==0.0.1
Finished processing dependencies for rocflavors==0.0.1
running develop
Checking .pth file support in build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/test-easy-install-35540.pth'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg

This directory does not currently exist.  Please create it and try again, or
choose a different installation directory (using the -d or --install-dir
option).
```

I have 3 questions:

1. Why does it NOT work in develop mode.
2. What is the difference between develop mode and not using it?
3. Why does it need to be a package? If I change a .py file in the package how does it make it back into my package directory. I don't think I understand the point of packaging. Does it put compiled python code into the package when I make a change?

Comment: See [Why does easy install want access to my rootfs for a "develop" install?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812400/14812532#14812532) and [Python "setup.py develop": is it possible to create ".egg-info" folder not in source code folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901776/13538687#13538687)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your virtualenv is activated. Instead of `python setup.py install develop`, try `pip install -e .`. Note the `.`, it means that you must be in the directory where setup.py is. If it fails, try with `sudo`.

Docs for pip: http://www.pip-installer.org/

Comment: That seemed to work. Can you point me to easy to understand documentation about python packages?

Comment: Well I learnt by doing and reading code written by others...  But there seem to be a doc: http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks! It seems when I use pip django doesn't pickup the template folder for my module. If I do `python setup.py develop` the templates folder gets picked up. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Yes, because your MANIFEST is wrong, check the one from another django app that has templates. In develop mode, symlinks are installed so it's easier to get all files. Also, another question should not be asked in a comment ;)